# I'm trying to create a Telegram bot using telebot which is also able to give birthday reminders

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Hi I am trying to create a teleragm bot via python using telebot that is able to send me a birthday reminder. I could not seems to get the code to work. I realize that the bot would call out the birthday correctly if i did not include the bot.polling() but when that happens, the bot does not take in any commands. if i include bot.polling, the bot works as per normal but doesn't calls out the birthday reminder. why is this so? and how can i fix this issue?

Disclaimer: I am very very new to programming and has only recently just started to pick up  python through the net. so please pardon me if my questions are very basics or the code seems messy.

```
import telebot
import time
import random

bot_token = 'some value'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token = bot_token)

#I have some more commands function in the bot but i have just listed 1 here for example purpose
@bot.message_handler(commands=["random"])  
def send_number(message):
    number = random.sample(range(1, 50), 6)

    bot.reply_to(message, "random number is..." + "\n" + str(number) )

def check_birthday():   
    today = time.strftime('%d%m')
    bdaefile = open('birthday.txt', 'r')
    for date in bdaefile:
        if today in date:
            line = date.split(' ')
            bot.send_message('chat ID', "Happy Birthday " + line[1] + ' ' + line[2] + '!')


schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(check_birthday) 

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling()
        schedule.run_pending()


    except Exception:

        time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've asked a very good question and it really can be confusing for a newcomer to Python. Let me split the answer to several.

**First lets look at telebot part:**

[source code of telebot.polling() method](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py#L387-L403)

The doc states this method shouldn't be called more than once. So it is not good to put that into a while cycle, since it will get called more than once. From the look into implementation it creates a separate thread which can then serve the bot's requests.

```py
...

bot.polling() #  this creates another Thread.

while True: # this loop is never exited
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(15)
```

**Now the schedule module:**

It is not wise to just suppress exceptions in try-except blocks, since you then will not know what was broken. So at least print the exception (you should use logging though).

```py
bot.polling() #  this creates another Thread.

while True: # this loop is never exited
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        time.sleep(15)
```

Now you should have more clues about what is happening.
The main thread should deal with schedule and bot thread, created by .polling() method should deal with telegram calls.

---

**More stuff to read/watch about this topic:**

I do suggest reading more about threading to run multiple blocking calls (read: `while True` loops) parallel to each other.
For example here: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Although Python has it's cons in threading, because of GIL.
https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Both of those are a bit advanced topics for beginner programmers. But I suggest reading them if you want to understand what is happening in your BOT vs SCHEDULE program.

Or watch a video. Personally I like the talk about GIL from PyCon:

https://kolodziejj.info/talks/gil/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvWmAIODi-s&list=PLyde45Tox-NfsQYj0AuToQNQehYIItZg6&index=22&t=0s

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer, a detailed answer was lacking whenever this question has been asked on SO or somewhere else. I have a question: `telebot.polling()` starts a thread. Now we have two threads, one is the main thread and one is the polling thread. If the scheduling is a part of main thread, does that mean we have solved the issue in question or do we have to make a seperate thread of scheduling?