# 'AsyncTeleBot' object has no attribute 'register_next_step_handler'

Tags: python-asyncio, py-telegram-bot-api

Trying to create simple ask, answer, remember telegram bot with [pyTelegramBot](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_version/index.html).
Everything were normal, when TeleBot were used. TeleBot.register_next_message_handler helped me a lot.
Example:

```
...

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '/start' in msg.text)
def send_welcome(msg):
    global cur_user
    cur_user = msg.from_user.id
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Да', callback_data='old'),
                 types.InlineKeyboardButton('Нет', callback_data='new'))
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Пора остановиться', callback_data='stop_bot'))
    greet = 'Бла...бла...бла\nМы знакомы?'
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, greet, reply_markup=keyboard)

...


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_processing(call):
    global user
    global cur_user
    if call.data == 'new':
        user = dict.fromkeys(user, None)
        nxt = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Как звать?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(nxt, get_name_ask_goal)


...
```

Still I need my bot to be asynchronous because of sleep time till message to be send from bot and with simultaneous possibility for user to send messages.
Tried to use AsyncTeleBot, but there is no register_next_step_handler function. I did't find out how to make bot wait user for the name typing and it is almost impossible to me to add register_next_step_handler function into particular files. Although found issue in [gitHub](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and no solution from 2017.

Tried

```
...
bot = AsyncTeleBot(os.getenv('token2'))
...

async def beep(chat_id) -> None:
    """Send the beep message."""
    await bot.send_message(chat_id, text='Beep!')
    aioschedule.clear(chat_id)


async def scheduler():
    global chat_id
    aioschedule.every(5).seconds.do(beep, chat_id).tag(chat_id)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(scheduler(), bot.polling(non_stop=True))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
...
```

Result:
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

I'm wondering:

- is there other appropriate libraries for my task?
- is there any simple solution to save user's message?
- is it possible to use asyncio with TeleBot that made Thread-style?

Hoping for any help.

Comment: It is pity to me, but there was the answer (even two) for my question or for part of it.
First one from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045734/im-trying-to-create-a-telegram-bot-using-telebot-which-is-also-able-to-give-bir).
Second one from [github](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/timer_bot.py).

There is no asyncio, but my task is implementable with those solutions.

Sorry, but when I were writing the question, I did not find these solutions and a lot of hours were spent to find out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> "register_next_step_handler" not implemented in AsyncTeleBot. You can use [states](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/asynchronous_telebot/custom_states.py) or create a simple database where the current state of the dialog with the user will be stored.

In the discussion [custom_states.py](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py) is provided as an example.

- Link to the discussion: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/discussions/1968
- Link to github issue:
  https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/1967